# compile a c++ app on ubuntu and run it on raspberry pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi-os

I'm on an opencv project that need to be deployed on rpi 4. I do prefer to reach this project development, testing a compiling on other device (lets say a labtop).

**My question which OS is compatible with this scenario.. Depian?**

Comment: Your laptop is most certainly x64, while the pi is ARM. This will complicate matters a lot.

Comment: Search Google for "cross compile for Raspberry".

Answer (score 1):

Developing and testing an application on one platform and deploying it on another platform is very common.

There are two approaches to this:

- Do all development and testing on the faster platform until you are ready for a pre-release, and then recompile it and retest on the target platform.
- Set up a cross compilation environment on the development platform and create binaries for the target platform for direct testing.

If you want to cross compile, you will need to pick an environment that supports targeting for the environment you have on the pi.  Note that multiple operating systems are available for the pi, and even if your development platform doesn't match the pi, you probably can set up a docker container or virtual machine that does support targeting whatever operating system you select for the pi.

Presumably if you are developing on a laptop, it has a different cpu than the pi, so binaries that run on your laptop will not run on the pi.  This is why you would need to cross compile.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to compile programs on almost any platform; this requires the installation of appropriate tools, libraries and toolchain. There are plenty of tutorials describing how to do this.

If you are looking at a single (or indeed few) project it is not worth the trouble and time, particularly on a Pi4 which is quite fast.

You can develop an application on any platform then compile on the Pi.

If you are looking at developing a complete OS or kernel it may be advantageous.